# How do I count occurrences with conditions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working in PostgreSQL. Suppose I have this `Person` table:

```
| id |          time         | name  |    type     |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2022-04-25 07:49:58.0 | Brian | Rejection 1 |
|  2 | 2022-04-25 07:49:58.0 | Brian | Rejection 2 |
|  3 | 2022-04-27 13:05:51.0 | Fredd | Rejection 1 |
|  4 | 2022-05-01 02:13:44.0 | Janet | Rejection 1 |
|  5 | 2022-05-01 03:45:06.0 | Janet | Rejection 2 |
|  6 | 2022-05-01 08:01:34.0 | Peter |   Approval  |
|  7 | 2022-05-01 12:12:53.0 | Frank | Rejection 2 |
|  8 | 2022-05-02 01:26:38.0 | Frank |   Approval  |
```

Note: We have 2 rejections types `Rejection 1` and `Rejection 2`.

I would like to make a query that counts the number of Rejections and the number of approvals for each name. However if there are 2 rejections at the same time, for the same name, like the two first rows in the example, it should only count as one.

Let me just add that it's possible for there to be one of each rejection types at the same time for the same name, but it's impossible for there to be two rejections of the same type at the same time for the same name.

So this is what I'm expecting it to return:

```
| name  | approvals | rejections |
----------------------------------
| Brian |     0     |     1      |
| Fredd |     0     |     1      |
| Janet |     0     |     2      |
| Peter |     1     |     0      |
| Frank |     1     |     1      |
```

The closest I could get to this is the following:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Approval' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) approvals,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Rejection 1' OR log_type = 'Rejection 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) rejections
FROM 
    person
GROUP BY 
    name
```

The problem with this is that it counts two rejections with same time and name as 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` to count the distinct `time`s if `log_type` is the `'Rejection X'`:

```
SELECT name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Approval' THEN 1 END) approvals,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN log_type IN ('Rejection 1', 'Rejection 2') THEN time END) rejections
FROM person
GROUP BY name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=11c370c20badc1642385a4407fdfbdc9).

Comment: I have a question. If I add a time period to the WHERE clause, I get rows with 0 approvals and 0 rejections. How do I eliminate rows without data?

Comment: You can try adding `WHERE time >= '2022-04-24 00:00:00.0' AND time < '2022-04-30 00:00:00.0'` to your query, then you'll have a few rows with both 0 approvals and 0 rejections.

Comment: @Ben no there are no rows with both 0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4a47a490b891ff229982b829cad6dea2

Comment: Yes sorry, it's if I have a row within the timeperiod that has a completely different type, try to add this row as row 4 ('4', '2022-04-28 02:13:44.0', 'Janet', 'type'), or I've done it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0cd9e92adae2a01ea81231ec1f966c3c.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I could add the following to the WHERE clause: `... AND log_type IN ('Approval', 'Rejection 1', 'Rejection 2')` ? Looks like it soves it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d6902e7ecfecfec014a71b48d63e4b2d

Comment: @Ben if there other log_types for which you don't want to get results then of course you should use that WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to remove duplicates, then use a simple count query to find the counts:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE log_type = 'Approval') approvals,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE log_type LIKE 'Rejection%') rejections
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time, name, SUBSTRING(log_type FROM '\w+')) rn
    FROM person
) t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: I get an error saying that 'rn' is unknown.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

We can fetch the date in the **CASE** and then use **DISTINCT COUNT**, which ignores nulls.
I have given a first query to show the intermediate results and the counts with and without **DISTINCT** to show what it is doing. I have used the test `LEFT(log_type,6) = 'Reject'` to group the 2 rejection types.
I suggest that it would be a good idea to round the time so that 2 rejections close together will be treated as repetitions. We the current queries event 1 second different will be treated as a different rejection.

> ```
> create table person(
>   id int,
>   time date,
>   name varchar(20),
>   log_type varchar(20));
>   insert into person values
> (  1,'2022-04-25 07:49:58.0','Brian','Rejection 1'),
> (  2,'2022-04-25 07:49:58.0','Brian','Rejection 2'),
> (  3,'2022-04-27 13:05:51.0','Fredd','Rejection 1'),
> (  4,'2022-05-01 02:13:44.0','Janet','Rejection 1'),
> (  5,'2022-05-01 03:45:06.0','Janet','Rejection 2'),
> (  6,'2022-05-01 08:01:34.0','Peter','Approval'),
> (  7,'2022-05-01 12:12:53.0','Frank','Rejection 2'),
> (  8,'2022-05-02 01:26:38.0','Frank','Approval');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

8 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT
>   name,
>   CASE WHEN LEFT(log_type,6) = 'Reject' THEN time END R,
>   CASE WHEN log_type = 'Approval' THEN time END A
> FROM person;
> ```

> ```
> name  | r          | a         
> :---- | :--------- | :---------
> Brian | 2022-04-25 | null      
> Brian | 2022-04-25 | null      
> Fredd | 2022-04-27 | null      
> Janet | 2022-05-01 | null      
> Janet | 2022-05-01 | null      
> Peter | null       | 2022-05-01
> Frank | 2022-05-01 | null      
> Frank | null       | 2022-05-02
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   name,
>   COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(log_type,6) = 'Reject' THEN time END) all_rejections,
>   COUNT(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Approval' THEN time END) all_approvals,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(log_type,6) = 'Reject' THEN time END) distinct_rejections,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN log_type = 'Approval' THEN time END) distinct_approvals
> FROM person
> GROUP BY name;
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | all_rejections | all_approvals | distinct_rejections | distinct_approvals
> :---- | -------------: | ------------: | ------------------: | -----------------:
> Brian |              2 |             0 |                   1 |                  0
> Frank |              1 |             1 |                   1 |                  1
> Fredd |              1 |             0 |                   1 |                  0
> Janet |              2 |             0 |                   1 |                  0
> Peter |              0 |             1 |                   0 |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=946fdb38c5b98872da58f02c641cb69b)*